# Error Checking and Trace Empty Cells

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel it's possible to locate formulas that have references to empty cells.

For example

A1 = 1

B1 = Empty

C1 = .5

D1 = A1 + B1 + C1

D1 will correctly calculate the value to be 1.5
However, error checking will identify that there is an error in the formula D1 and it can draw an arrow to this cell.

I need to alert the user if they have a reference to an empty cell.

When I try to record myself using the feature I get this

```
With Application.ErrorCheckingOptions
    .EvaluateToError = False
    .TextDate = False
    .NumberAsText = False
    .InconsistentFormula = False
    .OmittedCells = False
    .UnlockedFormulaCells = False
    .ListDataValidation = False
    .InconsistentTableFormula = False
End With

ActiveSheet.ClearArrows
```

The options for only checking for empty cells are setup correctly but the actual execution of the "Trace" function is completely ignored. Is there any way to cause this to happen automatically and then check the result of the test?

The function is "Formulas Tab" "Error Checking" "Formulas referring to empty cells" "Trace Empty Cell"

Comment: I could be wrong but I doubt there is a direct way of invoking the Trace Empty Error. Would it be helpful if a piece of code tells you which cell in the formula is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a VBA method to check Formulas referring to empty cells. This will not only tell you which formula it is but also which cell is empty.

To test this, in Sheet1, Cell A1 put this formula

```
=F1+G1+H1
```

Keep H1 Empty and fill F1 and G1

In Cell A5, put this formula

```
=A1*D5
```

Keep the Cell D5 empty.

Now paste this code in a module.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim RngFormulas As Range, fCell As Range, _
    DPrcd As Range, aCell As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        On Error Resume Next
        Set RngFormulas = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not RngFormulas Is Nothing Then
            For Each fCell In RngFormulas
                On Error Resume Next
                Set DPrcd = fCell.DirectPrecedents
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Not DPrcd Is Nothing Then
                    For Each aCell In DPrcd
                        If IsEmpty(aCell.Value) Then
                            Debug.Print aCell.Address & " in " & _
                            fCell.Formula & " is empty"
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

When you run the macro, you will see the output in the immediate window.

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try
    =IF(COUNTA(A1:A3),"ok","error") to find blanks in an array, and if that passes, then you can do whatever else needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to run Formulas > Error Checking on every page of my large spreadsheet, but I also could not find any VBA code to execute it.

The best I came up with was to just select errors using Goto > Special, which needs error handling to ignore the error that occurs when no errors are found (and it does not work for #N/A constants).

```
Dim r As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set r = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
If Err.Number <> 0 And Err.Number <> 1004 Then Stop
On Error GoTo 0
If Not r Is Nothing Then
    If r.Count > 0 Then
        r.Select
    End If
End If
```

If an error other than 1004 "No cells were found." occurs, I have not catered for it more than breaking the macro.