# Excel 2010 Copy and paste macro

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I need some help creating a macro. What I need it to do is Copy values from `E1:E10` on Sheet `Dont Use` to every 6th cell in column `D` on Sheet `Weekly Schedule` starting at `D10`. I only need one value per cell in column `D`, so `E1` goes to `D10`, `E2`-->`D16`...etc. I need to do this copy for the number listed in cell `A1` of sheet `Dont use`.

I used the code below to copy the layout of my form for as many as listed in cell `A1`. I'm wondering if there is a way to modify this code to complete what I need.

```
    Sub Copy()
    Dim X As Long
    X = 0
    Do Until X = Sheets("Dont Use").Range("A1")
    Rows("3:8").CopyDestination:=Sheets("WeeklySchedule").Rows("65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    X = X + 1
    Loop
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Code

```
Sub macro()
For i = 0 To 9
Var = Sheets("Dont Use").Cells(i + 1, 5).Value
Sheets("WeeklySchedule").Cells(10 + (i * 6), 4).Value = Var
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you works great. Is there a quick way to add error checking to this?

Comment: Similar question asked here you can check
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299620/error-checking-and-trace-empty-cells-from-a-vba-macro-in-excel